# Digital directory for Shopping mall

Tags: information-management, display, digital-asset-management

Looking for a digital directory solution for shopping mall

Requirements

1. should have touch display for customer interaction
2. should be able to list all the tenants,kiosks, shop present in the mall
3. should be able to display promotion offers,advertisement etc
4. floor maps to understand each and every floor in a mall
5. should have Shopping directory,way finder,shop finder,product finder etc
6. should have the option to show all the above details on a digital screen(wall mount or on a stand)
7. Money is not a matter for a perfect solution
8. should be multilingual

Note:  it must need some hardware(display unit) to showcase all the details in a mall, So would be good if any solution provider can provide hardware as well but it is not necessary(We can handle the display units as per our requirements)

Comment: When do you need it by? It would not be difficult to develop a custom solution.  Please let me know if you are interested.

Comment: I am sorry, Garbriell, but you have left it too late for us to consider doing it. You need custom hardware and software. And, even though you think that you know what you want, I mean no offence, the customer never knows what they want. There will always be changes and that will add time. Believe me when I say that we would like business, but I would not like to take the risk. Sorry.  While we can easily do that, we do not yet have an off the shelf solution, (although) we will probably develop one now, in case there is a next time. Your only chance, in that time, is to find an off the shelf

Comment: This is still in my mind, and I am considering developing something. It will take a while, though. Do you have an image of the shopping mall floor plan which you coudl share, for me to use as sample data?

Comment: I have stated development, but would like some idea as to the features that would be required. You haven't logged in for over a year now, but if you ever do & are still interested, please let me know & we can discuss it.

Comment: Lolx. Almost 5 years after you posted this, I have made a good start, but still really need to discuss it more with someone ... and you have not been seen since a month after you posted this, back in '16 :-(